# Undefined struct 'addrinfo' winsock2

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, winsock2

I encountered an error and I didn't find any solution (even over the internet)

I created a`Qt` app to receive data using a `TCP` protocol and plot them using `QcustomPlot`.

I have the following files:

**mainwindow.h** :

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QVector>
#include <iostream>

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    // ...

private:
    struct addrinfo _hints;
    struct addrinfo* _result = NULL;
    // ...
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp** :

```cpp
#pragma once
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QVector>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    //...
}
```

and the **main.cpp** file:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I have the following error:
'MainWindow::hints' uses undefined struct 'addrinfo' (compiling source file main.cpp).

I don't understand why I have this error, because I tested the same program in a classic consol app following the [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code) and it was working.
I believe it comes from the includes, but I still dont have a clue about which one causes that.

Comment: You use addrinfo but do not include the appropriate header. btw: Why do you want to use addrinfo at all when you use Qt? Qt has a good QtNetwork library which is even os-independent

Comment: Thank you I'll try with QtNetwork, since I am already familiar with winsock I thought it would be easier to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `#include` something in your `mainwindow.h` that defines `struct addrinfo`, because your `MainWindow` class has a member variable of that type. At the moment you include all the socket stuff only in your `*.cpp` file.

Comment: Oh my bad, I still don't get how the #include flow works, I thought if I include winsock twice I would have some issues.

Comment: Most headers guard themselves against multiple inclusions.  Just know that compilation starts at the `.cpp` file, not the `.h` file. `mainwindow.cpp` includes all of the Windows/Winsock headers before including `mainwindow.h`, so everything is already defined when the compiler sees the declaration of `MainWindow`. `main.cpp`, on the other hand, does not include any of the Windows/Winsock headers before including `mainwindow.h`. Since `MainWindow` uses `addrinfo`, you should have at least `<ws2def.h>` in `mainwindow.h` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You use `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` that prevents including many dependent header files and makes you include required header files explicitly. As for `addrinfo` you have to `#include <ws2def.h>`.

Comment: I think the problem is `main.cpp` because that file does not `#include` any Winsock-related include files. In `main.cpp` there is neither `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` nor `windows.h`...